# Existence of $\{0,1\}^X$ in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without the axiom of power set

Tags: set-theory

Is it possible to prove the existence of the set of all function from a given set $X$ to $\{0,1\}$ without using the axiom of power set in $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Comment: If you could, you wouldn't need a separate axiom of power set, would you?

Comment: Well yes... I was trying to prove that axiom of replacement implies the axiom of power set (reading on the internet I kinda understood that strictly speaking power set is not truly needed in ZFC, but I may be wrong) using the (class) function $F : \{0,1\}^X \to V : f \mapsto f^{-1}(\{1\})$ ($V$ is the proper class of all sets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can't do that. If you consider the set of all hereditarily countable sets (recall that $x$ is hereditarily countable if its transitive closure, $\operatorname{tcl}(x)$, is countable), denoted often by $H(\omega_1)$ or $H_{\omega_1}$, then $(H(\omega_1),\in)\models\sf ZFC^-$, that is $\sf ZFC$ without the Axiom of Power Set (and in fact with the stronger Axiom of Collection), but clearly $2^\omega$ is not hereditarily countable as it is not countable itself.

Moreover, given any $x\in H(\omega_1)$, we can diagonalise over $x\cap 2^\omega$ to construct some $f\colon\omega\to 2$ such that $f\notin x$. Since any such $f$ is in fact hereditarily countable, $f\in H(\omega_1)$. So indeed, $H(\omega_1)$ satisfies that "$2^\omega$ does not exist".

Comment: Uh, thank you!!